# Bedeutung von "wir beide schleppen schon alleine viele Jahre"

Tags: meaning

Ich habe mir [ein Lied angehört](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7X62OJG6Whg), verstehe aber folgenden Satz nicht ganz:

***Selbst wenn wir beide schon alleine viele Jahre schleppen***

Bedeutet das, dass die zwei schon lange sich kennen oder dass sie schon lange getrennte Wege laufen?

Vielen Dank

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nun geht der Satz in dem Lied aber noch ein Stück weiter. Das hilft uns hier, den Inhalt zu verstehen:

> *"Selbst wenn wir beide schon alleine viele Jahre schleppen, fühlt sich‘s an, als hätten wir im Sandkasten gesessen, ...*<sup>Fiva MC & Das Phantom Orchester - Dein Lächeln</sup>

Also sind die beiden Menschen, von denen das Lied handelt zuvor viele Jahre alleine gewesen. Dennoch haben sie nun eine Vertrautheit wie man es nur von Sandkastenfreunden aus der Kindheit kennt.

Mit *"schleppen"* kann nur die Mühsal, das *"sich durch das Leben schleppen"*, gemeint sein; hier poetisch im Gegensatz zum jetzigen Zustand beschrieben.

Comment: Hmmm... ich glaube es ist etwas voreilig zu schließen, dass mit schleppen "nur" "sich durchs Leben schleppen" sein kann... wenn dem so wäre, wo ist dann der Reflexiv? Ich sage nicht, dass es nicht so ist, aber es ist keineswegs klar

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich schätze, das ist eine Interpretations-Frage ;). Man kann unheimlich viel in dieses Wort hineininterpretieren.

Comment: ja, das habe ich doch versucht zu sagen.

Answer (score 4):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schleppen), kann *schleppen* etwas wie:

> [an]dauern, anhalten, sich ausdehnen, sich erstrecken, gehen, sich hinziehen, sich in die Länge ziehen, kein Ende nehmen, sich ziehen; (gehoben) fortwähren, währen; (umgangssprachlich) vorhalten; (bildungssprachlich veraltet) kontinuieren; (Medizin) persistieren

bedeuten.

Im Falle des Liedes würde ich schätzen, dass es entweder:

> Selbst wenn wir beide schon jeweils viele Jahre alt sind.

oder

> Selbst wenn wir beide uns schon viele Jahre kennen.

bedeutet. Ich höre diese Verwendung von *schleppen* zum ersten Mal und kann dir deswegen nicht genau sagen, welche Deutung es besser trifft.